# To calculate the total time elapsed using threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have this java code using Threads to calculate the time elapsed once the start button is hit till the stop button is not hit.

**I want to do this using Threads only**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

// This will count the elapsed time between running time of two threads.
class ThreadGame {

    JButton button;
    MyAction my_action;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadGame tg = new ThreadGame();
    }

    public ThreadGame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculate time - Game");
        button = new JButton("Start");
        button.addActionListener(new MyAction());
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class MyAction implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = (String) e.getActionCommand();

            final Timer timer = new Timer();

            if (text.equals("Start")) {
                button.setText("Stop");

                Thread start_time = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        timer.startTime();
                    }
                };

                start_time.start();
                try {
                    start_time.join();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                }

            } else {
                Thread stop_time = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        timer.stopTime();
                    }
                };

                Thread get_time = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        timer.getElapsedTime();
                        System.out.println(timer.elapsed);
                    }
                };
                stop_time.start();
                try {
                    stop_time.join();
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                }

                get_time.start();

                button.setText("Start");
            }
        }
    }

    class Timer {
        public double startTime = 0.0;
        public double stopTime = 0.0;
        public boolean running = false;
        public double elapsed = 0.0;

        public void startTime() {
            this.startTime = System.nanoTime();
            this.running = true;
        }

        public void stopTime() {
            this.stopTime = System.nanoTime();
            this.running = false;
        }

        // Elasped time in seconds
        public double getElapsedTime() {
            // double elapsed;
            if (running) {
                elapsed = ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000);
            } else {
                elapsed = ((stopTime - startTime) / 1000);
            }
            return elapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

`EDIT:` I have understand the problem: `timer` scope was the problem.

`EDIT 2:` Ok, it looks like I have to use `suspend` and `resume` in one thread only.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you're trying to accomplish, other than spinning up a lot of pointless threads. If all you're trying to do is keep track of the time between two button presses, save the start and end times somewhere, and update them in the `ActionListener`. If you're trying to make a counter that continually updates, take a look at `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: If you are just trying to learn threads then you should maybe fork a thread when start is pressed that counts some sort of value.  Then when stop is pressed you can call `thread.interrupt()` to stop the thread.

Comment: @Gray : Yes, i will use `Thread.interrupt()` or `suspend()` and `resume()` methods.

Comment: `Thread.suspend()` and `resume()` methods are deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: @Gray - that's a very bad way to accomplish timing.  See my edit below for an explanation.  If you're trying to learn a new programming concept, you should **always** learn that concept such that you're solving a problem that actually requires that concept for the solution. Otherwise, you'll have no idea when you're actually supposed to apply your new knowledge, making it impossible to use Occam's razor in designing a solution.

Comment: @Gray I was responding to your suggestion to fork a thread and increment a counter in a loop.  And by "my edit," I meant the third paragraph in my answer.  Sorry, there's a lot of edits.

Comment: Uh, I wasn't doing the loop as a timer @Ben.  He says that he is trying to experiment with threads.  I was just trying to give him other ideas for playing with threads.

Comment: @Gray, sorry - I just assumed that you meant to do that in place of the `Timer` class that he's presently using, for the purpose of measuring time.  I've written a lot of timing code, and it's one of my hot-button issues, largely because of things like this: http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time

Comment: Np @Ben.  Check my multithreading tag SO score.  I get it.  Oh, and I love that link too.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem is caused by the scope of `timer`.**  This should be a private instance variable, not a local method variable.  Further, wrapping calls to `startTime` and `endTime` in a thread's `run` method isn't gaining you anything, because these are incredibly short-lived calls.  But that's not the *real* problem here.

There's no reason to be running `Timer` in its own thread.  That is, without using a specialized real-time operating system, **using threads to solve the problem of measuring the duration between two events is *just plain wrong.***

You might think that you could create a thread with a loop that increments a `msec` variable after a `Thread.sleep(1)`.  **Don't do this!**  This kind of timing is also *just plain wrong*.  Your computer uses a preemptive multitasking model which means there's *no guarantee* that your thread will execute on a regular interval.  That is, there is nothing requiring that `Thread.sleep(1)` will sleep for some `maximum` duration.  The guarantee is that your thread will sleep for a **minimum of** 1ms.  This means there's no way to determine clock error if you're managing a clock yourself in software, and this error is not insignificant.  **Just don't do it!!** Time should always be measured by your operating system, preferably using an interrupt-based timer (which is how `System.nanoTime` works on most, if not all platforms).

Instead of using a thread, just call your `startTime` and `stopTime` methods directly from your original thread.

Try this:

```
class ThreadGame {

    JButton button;
    MyAction my_action;
    private final Timer timer = new Timer();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadGame tg = new ThreadGame();
    }

    public ThreadGame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculate time - Game");
        button = new JButton("Start");
        button.addActionListener(new MyAction());
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class MyAction implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = (String) e.getActionCommand();

            if (text.equals("Start")) {
                timer.startTime();
                button.setText("Stop");
            } else {
                timer.stopTime();
                button.setText("Start");
            }
        }
    }

    class Timer {
        public double startTime = 0.0;
        public double stopTime = 0.0;
        public boolean running = false;
        public double elapsed = 0.0;

        public void startTime() {
            this.startTime = System.nanoTime();
            this.running = true;
        }

        public void stopTime() {
            this.stopTime = System.nanoTime();
            this.running = false;
        }

        // Elasped time in seconds
        public double getElapsedTime() {
            return (this.startTime-this.stopTime)*1000000000.0;
        }
    }
}
```

**If you want to learn how to use threads, try writing an application that solves a problem for which threads are a good fit.**  For example, write a small Swing application that lets you download a file from the web.  As the file is downloading, update a progress bar in your UI. The download should happen in a worker thread separately from the UI thread, otherwise the UI will block during the download's progress.

Another example problem is to write a threaded ray tracer (here's an [example tutorial](http://www.codermind.com/articles/Raytracer-in-C++-Introduction-What-is-ray-tracing.html) written in C++).

If you want something simpler, write a Swing clock.  Use a loop within a separate thread to update the UI at a periodic interval, but **do not** use the loop to manage what time it is.  Again, don't try to keep time in the loop, just let the OS keep the time, and use the loop to schedule when the UI gets updated with the current OS time.

Comment: In short my point was that Threads are the **wrong** way to do this.

Comment: Ok, I have understand the problem. `timer` scope is the problem. I can now do this, but i have to use threads...

Comment: @Ben: I am not creating any application. I am just learning threads.

Comment: It is not needed to synchronize an ActionListenr. There is only one EDT (Event dispatching thread) in Swing, meaning that the actionPerformed method is invoked only by that Thread.

Comment: Thanks, Guillaume.  I was editing/commenting while a friend was waiting on me, I should've realized this.

Comment: @AmitYadav - see my edit for good resources to learn threading

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the start button press is starting a *different* `Timer` object than the stop-button button press is stopping because the `Timer` object is created every time when the `actionPerformed(...)` method is called.

The `Timer` needs to be a field in your `MyAction` class.  You also don't need all of the thread start/joins because the `Timer` object is very simple and fast.

Really, you can just use a `startTimeMillis` long field instead of a timer.  Something like:

```
class MyAction implements ActionListener {
   private long startTimeMillis;
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String text = (String) e.getActionCommand();

        if (text.equals("Start")) {
            startTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ...
         } else {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeMillis);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: AFAIK, there is only one EDT in Swing, meaning that if only Swing actions will modify your startTimeMillis, it is useless to make it `volatile`. There is no such thing as multiple Swing Threads.

Comment: Just read up on this and the docs seem to agree.  Thanks for the instruction @Guillaume.

Answer (score 0):

You're never calling `getElapsedTime()` that updates `elapsed` field.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this...

**-** Call `System.currentTimeMillis()` at the **Starting of threads.**

**-** Then again call `System.currentTimeMillis()` at the **end of threads.**

**-** `Subtract` the end with starting value to get the Elapsed time...

**/////////////////EDITED///////////////////////**

Make sure that the `method` trying to manipulate(ie. read and write) the `variable` holding the `System.currentTimeMillis()` must be synchronized, with `synchronized keyword`, so that Race Condition doesn't occur according to `Brian's Law`...

`If you are writing a variable that might next be read by another thread, or reading a variable that might have last been written by another thread, you must use synchronization, and further, both the reader and the writer must synchronize using the same monitor lock.`

Comment: Well now I've been corrected.  There is only one EDT thread.  Sorry for the misinformation @Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `Timer` when ever you click the button. Make timer a class variable of your `MyAction`

The code below should be sufficient to get elapsed time.

```
    class MyAction implements ActionListener {
        final Timer timer = new Timer();            
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = (String) e.getActionCommand();                
            if (text.equals("Start")) {
                button.setText("Stop");
                timer.startTime();
            } else {
                timer.stopTime();
                System.out.println(timer.elapsed);
                button.setText("Start");
            }
        }
    }
```